# Revertable file system - similar to Windows Volume Shadow Copy

Tags: windows, gratis, file-management

In Internet cafés or in casinos, the systems are protected by a special software that

- ensures that you have paid
- shuts down when the paid time is over
- reverts all files to the previous state

I didn't find the software that I was looking for, but the Computer Management module of [Intercafe (German)](http://www.blueimage.de/index.php/produkte/intercafe) does something similar (a bit less advanced, since it will just delete and not revert).

I'd like to use something similar at home, and since I don't pay :), I'm only interested in the last part.

Technically it would probably be a file system driver that

- reads from the original disk
- writes somewhere else
- if something was written, it is read from there
- at boot time, the write storage will be reset into original state

You could also argue that this is similar to Windows' built-in volume shadow copy.

The solution

- should be gratis
- for Windows
- redirects write access as defined before
- is configurable regarding the folders that have write permission and those which don't

I am not looking for a VCS (version control system), since the files might be very large. In my particular case, I want to protect a 3.8 GB file. SVN would keep a copy in the `.svn` folder.

I am also not looking for a VM snapshop. In fact it's a QEMU image and I don't want to run QEMU in a VM. Also, this approach would require ~10 GB extra disk space for the VHD file and I'd need a license.

Disk mirroring (like True Image for which I have a license) is overkill. I don't want to mirror a 4 TB disk just to keep a 3.8 GB file clean. In addition this would revert everything on the disk, not only a single file.

Comment: A commercial product (the price is not mentioned on the website, so it's probably expensive) might be [Deep Freeze](http://www.faronics.com/products/deep-freeze/standard/?redirect)

Comment: What about other solutions? Just keeping a copy of the original, then, at the end, wipe the file structure & copy back the original is by far the simplest way. However, this being Windows, user activity probably affetced the registry, so you might want to consider using a virtual machine, disk imaging, etc

Comment: @Mawg: that's what I do today. It requires you to strictly follow the process. Once you mix up the two, maybe you copy the wrong one. I have True Image as disk imaging solution, but it's overkill to mirror a 4 TB disk if I just need 4 GB. A VM is also overkill: it needs ~10 GB for a Windows installation + a license.

Answer (score 2):

There is a free windows program called [Steadier State](http://www.steadierstate.com) which can do what you are asking.
You didn't specify any Windows version. Steadier State lists Windows 7 Enterprise or Windows 7 Ultimate as requirements.

As for one which supports WindowsXP through Windows10, the Home Edition of [RollBack RxPC](http://www.horizondatasys.com/en/rollback_rx.ihtml) is freeware and should do the trick.

Comment: Great suggestion. Unfortunately I only have Windows 7 Professional.